# ExactTarget User provisioning: Is there a rest api?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Do you have RestAPI for provisioning users into Exacttarget and adding them into right roles? If so, can you point me to information on your user provisioning API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not yet, you will still have to use SOAP.  See https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html for the currently available REST routes.  See http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/account/ and http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/accountuser/ for the objects you need to do it in SOAP.